# how to rerun the python code automatically after "stack overflow error"

Tags: python, error-handling, stack-overflow, probability, restart

Ive written a code which will end up some desired outcome but there is a very high probability for the code to face "stack overflow error".

Is there anyway to restart the code automatically after "stack overflow error"?

I tried "try"-and-"except" but it didn't work.

update:

Someone asked for the code i cant add the code entirely but it is the last part of the code which is consist of a function which includes a series of functions (total number of functions needs to be equal to number of teams [which is a a list] minus 1)
if i run the code with seven or eight functions it would 100 percent work but as i run the code with more functions in the series the probability of facing stack overflow error will rise significantly.

There will be some possible desired outcome but there would be a lot of possible ways to face stack overflow error too.

```py
   def draw(destinationfile, teams):
       open(destinationfile,"w").close()
       all_matches(teams)
       draw_reg(1, destinationfile)
       draw_reg(2, destinationfile)
       draw_irreg(3, destinationfile)
       draw_reg(4, destinationfile)
       draw_irreg(5, destinationfile)
       draw_irreg(6, destinationfile)
       draw_reg(7, destinationfile)
       draw_irreg(8, destinationfile)
       draw_reg(9, destinationfile)
       draw_irreg(10, destinationfile)
       draw_irreg(11, destinationfile)
       draw_reg(12, destinationfile)
       draw_reg(13, destinationfile)
  draw("draw result.txt", leagueteams)
```

Comment: please add some code

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
while True:
  try:
    foo()
  except:
    continue
  break;
```

If it fails (=Ending in the except clause; exception is thrown), it goes to the start of the loop and tries again, otherwise, it just breaks from the looop.